# Python convert set string to set

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, set

I have a string  that looks like

```
{'dir1/dir2/k8s-dag-model.py', 'dir1/dir2/[updated]airflow-issue.txt', 'dir1/dir2/1.log', 'dir1/dir2/cloud_formation.py', 'dir1/dir2/example_sftp_to_s3.py', 'dir1/dir2/catalog_sales.csv', 'dir1/dir2/dep-dremio0.sh', 'dir1/dir2/store_sales (1).csv', 'dir1/dir2/example_datasync_1.py', 'dir1/dir2/spark-svc.yaml'}
```

I want to convert it to set how can i do that?

using  set(a.split(",")) converting it into

```
{" 'dir1/dir2/spark-svc.yaml'}", " 'dir1/dir2/store_sales (1).csv'", " 'dir1/dir2/[updated]airflow-issue.txt'", " 'dir1/dir2/dep-dremio0.sh'", " 'dir1/dir2/example_sftp_to_s3.py'", " 'dir1/dir2/catalog_sales.csv'", " 'dir1/dir2/cloud_formation.py'", " 'dir1/dir2/1.log'", "{'dir1/dir2/k8s-dag-model.py'", " 'dir1/dir2/example_datasync_1.py'"}
```

here I have to remove ' and {,} . Is there a standard way to do it.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(string)`, don't forget to `import ast`

Comment: Your input is a set already, a set of strings...

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a String to a set/list using `literal_eval`

```
import ast
x = "{'dir1/dir2/k8s-dag-model.py', 'dir1/dir2/[updated]airflow-issue.txt', 'dir1/dir2/1.log', 'dir1/dir2/cloud_formation.py', 'dir1/dir2/example_sftp_to_s3.py', 'dir1/dir2/catalog_sales.csv', 'dir1/dir2/dep-dremio0.sh', 'dir1/dir2/store_sales (1).csv', 'dir1/dir2/example_datasync_1.py', 'dir1/dir2/spark-svc.yaml'}"
y = ast.literal_eval(x)

print(y)
```

Since the same works for a list too a similar answer for a list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894296/5236575

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval